# Android | Radio buttons wont do anything and keep pressed

Tags: java, android, radio-button

Im trying to make a currency converter homework (i am new to programming)

made everything but the radio button is keeped pressed and isnt doing nothing
(not puting text into the TextView and the radio buttons is locked on "pressed" mode

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_convert);

    mResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    mToConvert = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.toConvert);
    mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioG);
    mDollar = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.dollar);
    Meuro = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.euro);

    mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rGroup, int checkedId)
        {

            switch (mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())
            {
            case R.id.dollar:
            Double dollarConvert = Double.valueOf(mToConvert.getText().toString()); //convert the string to int
            double price = dollarConvert * 1.28;
            mDollar.setChecked(true);
            Meuro.setChecked(false);
            String result = mToConvert.getText().toString();
            mResult.setText(result + price);
            break;

            case R.id.euro:
                Double euroConvert = Double.valueOf(mToConvert.getText().toString()); //convert the string to int
                double value = euroConvert * 1.28;
                mDollar.setChecked(false);
                Meuro.setChecked(true);
                String result1 = mToConvert.getText().toString();
                mResult.setText(result1 + value);
                break;

                default:;
            }
        }
    });


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to set [RadioGroup.setoncheckedchangelistener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener%28android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener%29) for RadioGroup to do some Action when check changes event fire.

```
mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rGroup, int checkedId)
    {
              //do your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: what should i write in "int checked id"?

Comment: nothing just copy/past your switch statement inside onCheckedChanged

Comment: @YonatanBalas : just change `switch (mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())` to `switch (checkedId)`

Comment: found the solution.. radio buttons was not in the radio group... but your souloution was helpfull and neccesary to make it work

Comment: @YonatanBalas : do one more thing put validation for EditText before converting to double to avoid application crashing